# TYPO3 how to get nested private members

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript, fluid

Here is the data struct in question:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResultprototypeobject (2 items)
0 => Plistvendor\Plistkey\Domain\Model\Partnerprototypepersistent entity (uid=16, pid=50)
1 => Plistvendor\Plistkey\Domain\Model\Partnerprototypepersistent entity (uid=17, pid=50)
  name => 'Egal' (4 chars)
  nachname => 'Nachname' (8 chars)
  position => 'position2' (9 chars)
  adresse => 'adresse 123 lorem ipsum' (24 chars)
  land => 'Deutschland' (11 chars)
  bild => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReferenceprototypepersistent entity (uid=98, pid=50)
  skype => 'skypename' (9 chars)
  telefon => '90853490583094' (14 chars)
  email => 'mail@email.de' (13 chars)
  division => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyObjectStorageprototypeobject (1 items)
  language => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyObjectStorageprototypeobject (1 items)
    000000004dac554500000000513665c6 => Plistvendor\Plistkey\Domain\Model\Languageprototypepersistent entity (uid=6, pid=50)
       name => 'en' (2 chars)
       uid => 6 (integer)
       _localizedUid => 6 (integer)modified
       _languageUid => 1 (integer)modified
       _versionedUid => 6 (integer)modified
       pid => 50 (integer)
       uid => 17 (integer)
       _localizedUid => 17 (integer)modified
       _languageUid => -1 (integer)modified
       _versionedUid => 17 (integer)modified
       pid => 50 (integer)
```

Now my Question is how can I access `_languageUid` in either Fluid or PHP?

For further refference here is my controller code. I know it's pretty bad so I'm open to any suggestions that wouldn't cost too much time.

```
 public function listAction() {
    $lang     = $_GET['L'];
    $partners = $this->partnerRepository->GetAll();
    foreach ($partners as $key              => $value) {
        foreach ($value->getlanguage() as $key => $lval) {
            echo $lval;
        }
    }
    $this->view->assignMultiple(array('partners' => $partners));
}
```

In this controller I can do echo `$lval->getUid();` and it will return the language Uid however I need to acces the `_languageUid`/`sys_language_uid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a public getter method for this property, otherwise you can't get it with fluid. Take an example at https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news/blob/master/Classes/Domain/Model/News.php#L1158-L1161

```
public function getSysLanguageUid()
{
    return $this->_languageUid;
}
```

In PHP, you can use the method `_getProperty('_languageUid')`